# Is there any way I can remove my gravatar image from showing up?

Tags: support, gravatar

Is it possible to remove the link to my gravatar picture?

I don't see anywhere on the site to be able to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "link to gravatar picture"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops, totally misread your question. The only way to remove the automated avatar image without putting a new one there would be to sign up for Gravatar with the same email you use for your SE profile and use a blank image as your Gravatar.

---

<s>No, there's no way to not use Gravatar, but you have several options:</s>

- Change your email address to be of the form `username+blablabla@example.com`. Anything between the `+` symbol and the `@` sign usually gets ignored, so email from SE will still be routed to you, while the Gravatar hash will be changed. (On some services, this will be the `-` sign, and on some others, all symbols will be important, so check with your email provider.
- Use an alternate email address and setup forwarding to your regular email for SE emails. (Most free online providers like Gmail provide this).
- Remove your email from your profile.

Comment: Wow, email tags are supported? So I guess that would answer my potential question of how can I have a different a different image per account.  Awesome, it works.  :)